# Dalekjs test scripts on OS windows-8 64-bit Chrome doesn't run?

Tags: google-chrome, phantomjs, dalekjs

I have successfully installed Dalekjs on windows OS but when i try to run my first test script , the test doesn't run. Though it runs successfully on PhontomJs but when running with real browser, the browser opens and closes and shows error.

```
Running tests
Running Browser: Google Chrome
OS: Windows NT 6.2 x86_64
Browser Version:

RUNNING TEST - "Page title is correct"
> OPEN http://google.com
x TITLE
0 EXPECTED: Google
0 FOUND: [object Object]
0 MESSAGE: It has title
x TEST - "Page title is correct" FAILED

0/1 assertions passed. Elapsed Time: 4.99 sec
```

When running on phantonJS, it shows

```
Running Browser: PhantomJS
OS: windows 8 32bit
Browser Version: 1.9.7

RUNNING TEST - "Page title is correct"
> OPEN http://google.com
* TITLE It has title
* 1 Assertions run
* TEST - "Page title is correct" SUCCEEDED
```

Does DalekJs have problem with Window8 64bit system because it runs fine on 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

I analysed the problem, it seems like this is a bug during the system architecture check.
Could you please file an issue [here](https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek-browser-chrome/issues?state=open)?!